# AngularJS Two way data binding

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

In my controller I have the following data:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myappl.mymodule')
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'myService'];

function MyController($scope, 'myService') {
    $scope.vm = this; 
    var vm = this;

    vm.myService = myService;

    vm.userManagement = userManagement.data;
    vm.userManagementSomeDataObjects = vm.userManagement.someDataObjects;
```

Somewhere in this controller I have a function which first gets data from backend and than invoke **showModal**:

```
function modalForUserInteraction() {
        vm.myService.getData(parameters).success(function(data) {
            vm.modalService.showModal(data, vm.userManagement, vm.userManagementSomeDataObjects);
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log('error');
        });
    }
```

The modal- controller looks like this:

```
...
function showModalService($modal, $stateParams, otherService) {
    var service = {
        showModal: showModal
    };      
    return service;

    ////////////

    function showModal(data, userManagement, userManagementSomeDataObjects) {
         var myModal = $modal.open({
            controller: ModalController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            windowClass: "modal fade in",
            resolve: {  
                userManagement: function() {
                return userManagement;
            },
            userManagementSomeDataObjects: function() {
                return userManagementSomeDataObjects;
            }
            },  
            templateUrl: 'url/to.html'
        });
        return myModal;
```

and in the modal controller there is a method like this one:

```
function ModalController(userManagement, userManagementSomeDataObjects) {
var vm = this;

...

function doSomeActionAfterButtonClickAtModal() {
    otherService.getDataFromBackend(params).success(function(data) {

        userManagement = data;
            userManagementSomeDataObjects = data.someDataObjects;

})error(function(data) {
    console.log('error');
});
}
```

If I do it like this:

**userManagement = data;** and **userManagementSomeDataObjects = data.someDataObjects;** than the new data is not set.

If I set each property separately of the objects than it works more often than not but somethimes it does not.

My question now would be what I can do in order to get it work. 
Currently I do not have a $scope- variable in my modal and actually I don't know 
if **$scopeOfModal.$apply()** would help and I also don't know how to get access from modal to **MyController - $scope**.

I would be glad for any hint in this direction.

Thanks a lot!

**[EDIT]**
Here is an image of my currently viewed (right) an on the left side the object, which should be shown after setting in modal- function.

[image]

[EDIT]

is there any posibility to pass parameters to this function in the modal controller:

```
this.previewArchivedSchedule = function(hereINeedParamerts) {
             alert('archivedScheduleIntervalContainerId: ' + hereINeedParamerts); 
          };
```

Comment: Check my answer for [Pass variable to modal without using $scope](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33795989/5535245). If covers sending data in both directions.

Comment: It has a working Plunk and if you find it useful, give it an "up".

Comment: Have you had any luck solving your issue using my solution or the one linked by georgeawg? 

If you are having problems, feel free to add comments for clarification or edit your original post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example, it seems to be the right solution for my problem. I am still fighting with parameters: Is it possible to set function parameters from modal html to Modal controller function?

Comment: I did it - great solution - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me just like it may have nothing to do with angular, just some confusion with javascript variable references.

First you pass `userManagement` from `showModalService.showModal` to `ModalController` via `resolve`.

So now `ModalController` has a reference to the same object as `showModalService`.

However, in `ModalController`, you reassign the `userManagement` variable to point to `data` instead. So now the `userManagement` variable inside `ModalController` isn't pointing at the injected object anymore, because you've reassigned it. This has nothing to do with angular two-way data binding, it's just javascript variable assignment. You've lost your reference to the original object.

`showModalService` still has a reference to the instance that it sent in via resolve, it has no idea that you swapped the reference out in the `ModalController`.

I'd try sending over an object encapsulating the data you want to share to fix this problem.

```
function showModal(data, userManagement, userManagementSomeDataObjects) {
     var myModal = $modal.open({
        controller: ModalController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        windowClass: "modal fade in",
        resolve: {  
            sharedData: function() {
                return {
                    userManagement: userManagement,
                    userManagementSomeDataObjects: userManagementSomeDataObjects
                }
        }, 
        templateUrl: 'url/to.html'
    });
    return myModal;
```

Then manipulate the properties on the shared object instead of overwriting references.

```
function ModalController(sharedData) {
var vm = this;

...

function doSomeActionAfterButtonClickAtModal() {
    otherService.getDataFromBackend(params).success(function(data) {
        sharedData.userManagement = data;
        sharedData.userManagementSomeDataObjects = data.someDataObjects;
    })error(function(data) {
        console.log('error');
    });
}
```